# Yup validation in form with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, yup

I have a form that can create or edit an object. Each attribute is required so you cannot create/save an object without a valid A and B. I'm using yup and TypeScript latest version.

```
interface Exemple{
  A: number;
  B: number;
}
```

To do that I have two number inputs that can return a number or NaN if empty or invalid number.
I made a validation function that I can then add to yup with addMethod :

```
export function validateExemple(): Yup.ObjectSchema<Exemple> {
  return Yup.object<Exemple>().shape({
    A: Yup.number()
      .transform((value) => (isNaN(value) ? undefined : value))
      .required()
      .max(20)
      .min(-20),
    B: Yup.number()
      .transform((value) => (isNaN(value) ? undefined : value))
      .required()
      .max(30)
      .min(-30),
  });
}
```

I need to convert Nan value to undefined to avoid an exception on min/max. This function work like intended despite the type error :

```
Type 'ObjectSchema<{ A: number | undefined; B: number | undefined; }, Exemple, { A: undefined; B: undefined; }, "">' is not assignable to type 'ObjectSchema<Exemple, AnyObject, any, "">'.
```

My problem is that I don't want to change the base type to number | undefined because unless I'm not in the form A and B cannot be undefined. I thought about using two different types (Exemple and ExempleForm) but that would duplicate all my types used in forms in my application.

I'm looking for a way to write a validation function that does the same thing, with this type and without the error.

Is there a solution for what I'm asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try like this :

```
export function validateExemple(): Yup.ObjectSchema<Exemple> {
  const numberSchema = Yup.number()
                          .nullable()
                          .transform((value) => (isNaN(value) ? null : value));
                                return Yup.object<Exemple>().shape({
                                   A: numberSchema.required().max(20).min(-20),
                                   B: numberSchema.required().max(30).min(-30),
                                });
  }
```

As you can see here, you can use `nullable` method in `Yup` instead of `undefined`.

Comment: Your answer made me realise the problem was elsewhere.

To make it short, I want all my application to have the same message on .required (using i18n to translate), so I made a custom required() function and tried to add it to all schema using addMethod

```Yup.addMethod(Yup.Schema, 'requiredValue', function requiredValue() {
  return this.required('form.required');
});```

```declare module 'yup' {
  interface NumberSchema {
    requiredValue(): NumberSchema;
  }
}```
NumberSchema type is Yup.Maybe<number>
Yup documentation is a little lacking with typescript

Comment: you are right. maybe we can discuss more, my answer is not usefull?

Comment: Unless I find a way to declare a required function that work everywhere in typescript I'll just replace everything with .required('form.required'). I don't like duplication but it seems to be the easiest way to fix my issue.

I really appreciate your answer tho, made me realised something that made me waste a lot of time. Thank you very much!

Comment: I hope your success in your project.